# R: Separate Text String by Space and Remove Tabs, Line Breaks, Etc

Tags: r, text-mining, stringr

After reading an HTML table, my `name` column appears with records as follows:

```
\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMike Moon\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
```

The following code fails to generate the correct values in the First and Last name columns

```
separate(data=nametable, col = Name, into = c("First","Last"), sep= " ")
```

Curiously, the `First` column is blank, while the `Last` column contains only the person's first name.

How could I correctly turn this column into the `First` and `Last` column desired (i.e...

```
First     Last
Mike      Moon
```

Data example per recommendation of @r2evans and as appearing in correct answer code below:

```
nametable <- data.frame(Name="\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMike Moon\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Please make this question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/). This starts with providing reusable data, such as `dput(head(nametable))`. The next step is ensuring you include all non-base packages, where I am assuming you mean `tidyr::separate`.

Comment: If I make a tibble with just this string in it, `tidyr::separate` works for getting first & last names; they just each have lots of escaped characters. So there might be something missing from your post to recreate the problem

Comment: @r2evans thank you for the suggestion and for the quick answer. I've added the example data as reflected in your answer code to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to trim whitespace from the field before moving on. `trimws` removes *"leading and/or trailing whitespace from character strings"* (from [`?trimws`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/trimws.html)).

Data:

```
nametable <- data.frame(Name="\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMike Moon\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
nametable %>% mutate(Name = trimws(Name))
#        Name
# 1 Mike Moon
```

I infer that you are using `dplyr` as well as `tidyr`, so I'm using it here. It is also really straight-forward to do `nametable$Name <- trimws(nametable$Name)` without the `dplyr` usage.
From here, it's as you initially coded:

```
nametable %>%
  mutate(Name = trimws(Name)) %>%
  tidyr::separate(col=Name, into=c("First", "Last"))
#   First Last
# 1  Mike Moon
```